# NullPointerException when using WindowsFileChooserUI

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jfilechooser

I get this run-time error, i am trying to make the java file chooser look like the windows one.

error code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsFileChooserUI.installComponents(WindowsFileChooserUI.java:306)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI.installUI(BasicFileChooserUI.java:173)
at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsFileChooserUI.installUI(WindowsFileChooserUI.java:150)
at Main.getImg(Main.java:49)
at Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

Code:

```
JFileChooser fico = new JFileChooser();
WindowsFileChooserUI wui = new WindowsFileChooserUI(fico);
wui.installUI(fico);
int returnVal = fico.showOpenDialog(null);
```

Comment: I have just executed 4 lines of code in your question, and no exceptions. can you specify your question or send more codes?

Answer (score 6):

When the UI object is initializing, it is trying to read some UI defaults from the UI manager that it expects to exist (the `FileChooser.viewMenuIcon` property), which always exists under the Windows L&F but not under the Metal L&F.

Firstly, a warning.  Mixing multiple L&F at the same time in Swing is hazardous.  Swing is really only meant to be run with one L&F at a time.

A better way to set up a 'special' file chooser is to initialize everything through the UI manager when your application starts up.

```
//Do this first thing in your application before any other UI code

//Switch to Windows L&F
LookAndFeel originalLaf = UIManager.getLookAndFeel();
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

//Create the special file chooser
JFileChooser windowsChooser = new JFileChooser();

//Flick the L&F back to the default
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(originalLaf);

//And continue on initializing the rest of your application, e.g.
JFileChooser anotherChooserWithOriginalLaf = new JFileChooser();
```

Now you have two components with two different L&Fs which you can use.

```
//First chooser opens with windows L&F
windowsChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

//Second chooser uses default L&F
anotherChooserWithOriginalLaf.showOpenDialog(null);
```