# How to create a simple folder chooser with swing like this?

Tags: java, swing, filechooser

I'm learning java swing recently.
Please don't tell me it's out of date.
I know. I want to create a folder selector like this, there is nothing extra.

[image: browse]

Instead of the following, there are many other elements on it
[image: browse file]

Comment: You could adapt it from the `JTree` on the left in this [File Manager](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4451/7784).

Comment: I think this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/4350171/11121568 is the answer to your question

Comment: @Soroush Shemshadi It seems not. I want only the folder image, as shown in Figure 1

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Doesn't Java Swing have ready-made settings?

Comment: *"Doesn't Java Swing have ready-made settings?"* Plenty of them, but I'm figuring that by 'settings' you mean 'components. The answer to that is 'many, just not the one you seem to want'. Toughen up and use a `JTree`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23804675/list-files-and-directories-with-jtree-and-file-in-java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Browse for folder dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779360/browse-for-folder-dialog)

Comment: @Charlie Hello,I know this usage, but it is not the answer I want. What I want is a simple folder selector like Figure 1. It has no extra buttons and input boxes, just select the folder

Comment: @JoopEggen Is it the only way to achieve it by using jtree?

Comment: @UlricaLin Did you try the mode? fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode( JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

Comment: There were some "Explorer" mini-libraries around, but the JFileChooses will not have an extra JTree in the background for just this. Alternative you could add your own JPanel to the original JFileChooser. Either with a JTree to the left, or maybe a clickable bread crumb bar at the top: `C: > Users > Butler > Documents`.

Answer (score 0):

java swing has a `jfilechooser` which you can use. refer Java Swing [Here](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-swing)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html

Comment: I know. But I can only achieve the effect of Figure 2. What I want is the effect of Figure 1. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: please add some code that will make your answer more elaborate and clear for others to come without having to go to external pages

Comment: @st.huber Ulrica has shown us a picture what she would like to achieve. Could code add any clarity to this?

Comment: @Ulrica Lin Andrew Thompson has given you the link to his FileManager class. Extract the JTree part and most of the work is done. If this is too much for you, have a look at the FileDialog class. It is not giving exactly what you want, but uses the OS's file dialog, and only few lines of code are needed to have it shown.

Comment: @Jörg I didn't ask Ulrica for more code but Dawud. Some code that shows how the jfilechooser works would make the answer more useful. Furthermore the `jfilechooser` was mentioned but the link is to the general swing documentation and not to the `jfilechooser`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaFX:

```
DirectoryChooser directoryChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
directoryChooser.setInitialDirectory(new File("src"));

Button button = new Button("Select Directory");
button.setOnAction(e -> {
    File selectedDirectory = directoryChooser.showDialog(primaryStage);
    System.out.println(selectedDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
 });
```

Javadoc:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/stage/DirectoryChooser.html

It does indeed call the Windows browse for folder dialog:

JavaFX src:
https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/86b854dc367fb32743810716da5583f7d59208f8/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/native-glass/win/CommonDialogs_Standard.cpp#L368

Win32 docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shbrowseforfolderw

Comment: I don't think it is a valid answer for a question starting with "_I'm learning java swing_"

Comment: Well, good news! You can use Swing and JavaFX together! I looked in the src of the standard runtime and didn't see the appropriate native call, so I don't think there's a swing option outside JNI or third party libraries.